# Class balancing of the dataset

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, smote

While performing the SMOTE for balancing the class data, what should be the proportion of both class? For instance, if we have 100 instances, what (%) should be the Yes class and what should be the No class?

Comment: There is no rule of thumb to determine that parameter. Only thing to remember is that SMOTE creates synthetic observations so over use might be detrimental for the model. I would suggest trying various combinations and checking which works for you better.

Comment: @AmanMathur, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in the comment, there is not rule of thumb. One has to do a lot experimentation.

Based on how much data you have, bringing minority class to be be equal (50-50) to the majority class can be misleading the model.

You can also try **ADASYN** during your experimentation.

**ADASYN** is a improved version of SMOTE. What it does is same as SMOTE just with a minor improvement. After creating those sample it adds a random small values to the points thus making it more realistic. In other words instead of all the sample being linearly correlated to the parent they have a little more variance in them i.e they are bit scattered.

You can read about the implementation [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/smote-and-adasyn-handling-imbalanced-data-set-34f5223e167)